# Facebook REST calls for mobile cross-platform app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I am writing some C++ code for a cross-platform app and I would like to know if it's possible to integrate Facebook connection via REST calls to avoid adding the SDKs for each platform and writing native code for each one of them.

I read about the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) but I still have a question:
 When a user presses a "Login with Facebook" button in your app and he is already logged in through the Facebook App, he expects to be logged in automatically. I know the Facebook SDKs (both Android and iOS) do this and read about the [Windows Phone Login process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone), but is it possible to do this directly from C++ to avoid the increase in app size (through the addition of SDKs) and writing pseudo-duplicate code?

Comment: You need to use the Native SDKs on iOS and Android to get approved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **NO**. While you ***can*** directly access the Facebook API through their REST URLs' (this is documented), the fact is that your app needs to use the Facebook SDK and access the graph API through their Java classes (`GraphUser` and `Response`) and methods (`executeAsync()` and `executeAndWait()`) for your app to receive permissions. This is mentioned in their conditions for approving permissions.